# How to catch and ignore an Error call in Haskell

Tags: haskell, error-handling, functional-programming

I'm trying to understand how to handle calls error in Haskell. For example:
I have this graph

```
import Data.Map (Map,empty,member,insert,keys,(!))
import Graphviz

-- | A directed graph
data Graph v = Graph
    { arcsMap :: Map v [v]     -- A map associating a vertex with its successors
    , labelMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz label of each node
    , styleMap :: Map v String -- The Graphviz style of each node
    }deriving (Show,Eq, Ord)
```

And I have the function

```
-- | Returns the successors of a vertex in a graph in ascending order
--
-- We say that `v` is a successor of `u` in a graph `G` if the arc `(u,v)`
-- belongs to `G`.
--
-- Note: Returns the empty list if the vertex does not belong to the graph.
--
-- >>> successors 1 emptyGraph
-- []
-- >>> successors 1 $ addArc (1,2) emptyGraph
-- [2]
-- >>> successors 1 $ addArcs emptyGraph [(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)]
-- [2,3]
successors :: Ord v => v -> Graph v -> [v]
successors v (Graph arcs labels styles) = arcs ! v
```

The documentation of the operator (!) says :  "O(log n). Find the value at a key. Calls error when the element cannot be found."

I want to return an empty list [] when the element can't be found

How should I handle this ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [**the `!?` operator** (`Ord k => Map k a -> k -> Maybe a`)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:-33--63-) here. This will return a `Nothing` in case the key does not exist, and `Just v` with `v` the value in case that exists, as specified by the documentation:

> *O(log n)*. Find the value at a key. **Returns `Nothing` when the element can not be found**.

Then we still need to convert that to an empty list. We can use [**`fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) for that, here we first give a "default" value to use in case of a `Nothing`, and then we pass it a `Maybe a`. In case it is a `Nothing`, we use the default, in case it is a `Just v`, it will return `v`:

```
import Data.Map (Map,empty,member,insert,keys,(!?))
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

successors :: Ord v => v -> Graph v -> [v]
successors v (Graph arcs _ _) = fromMaybe [] (arcs !? v)
```

or as [@Bergi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252298/how-to-catch-and-ignore-an-error-call-in-haskell/58252328?noredirect=1#comment102874804_58252328), we can use [**`findWithDefault :: Ord k => a -> k -> Map k a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:findWithDefault):

```
import Data.Map (Map,empty,member,insert,keys,findWithDefault)
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

successors :: Ord v => v -> Graph v -> [v]
successors v (Graph arcs _ _) = findWithDefault [] v arcs
```

Comment: [`findWithDefault`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:findWithDefault) might be even easier to use

Comment: Heyy, thank you so much for the explanation. I just tried the operator !? with fromMaybe and it seems to work very well. I was curious for an easier way to do the same job and i also tried findWithDefault but this error appears :Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        v ~ Map (Map v [v]) [v]

Comment: @VelyynS: sorry, I swapped the last two parameters, now it should (hopefully) work.